# Vim command to create database on laravel

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, sqlite

I was following a tutorial where I found the guy to create a sqlite database file with vim command.But in my cmd the vim command is not working.I installed sqlite but still I don't anything happening with vim command

I have the the same vim database/database.sqlite but doesn't work

vim database/database.sqlite

What is vim command?How to avail it in my pc?How to create sqlite database file with sqlite

Comment: you can try with `touch database/database.sqlite` from the shell

Comment: But heared that touch is for Mac OS.but I'm in windows

Comment: just create an empty file

Answer (score 2):

You can install vim for windows cmd. First install sqlite tools from https://www.sqlite.org/2020/sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3310100.zip save it in drive as 'C:\sqlite3' and set $PATH as 'C:\sqlite3' in  the environment variables. And also download VIM for windows. Then in cmd as you type vim database/database.sqlite. It will run. If it doesnt run the first time close the cmd and run it again. It worked for me kinda like this

Answer (score 0):

as i see you are trying to use vim on windows

vim is a file editor application on Linux OS 
if you have linux and vim command not working you can install it simply with this

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install vim
```

if you are using windows you can use notepad or notepad++ to edit files

for making sqlite database on windows you can use this application

SQLite Expert Professional

you can download it form here:
    http://www.sqliteexpert.com/download.html

just simply install and click on new database , create your tables then save it 
thats all

Comment: Vim is a cross-platform editor and has been available for DOS/Windows for a long time, see: https://www.vim.org/download.php These days using WSL or WSL2 is yet another way to get Linux tooling (including Vim) on Windows. Though yes your answer is Ok in the sense you don't *need* Vim for what they described there, any editor should probably do...

Answer (score -1):

[Please download and install vim](https://www.vim.org/download.php) Try again "vim database/database.sqlite"

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34183588)